# Display default qty in the drop-down configurable product options

Tags: magento

i want to Display default qty in the drop-down configurable product options rather than choose an option .how to make it posible.
 i edited some javascript codes still not working
i used an extension Easylife Switcher still not working
Any help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the default magento dropdown in attributes rather than using Easylife Switcher extension